# RestKt object updatding

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

I have a question about RestKit object updating.

I'm using a category of the NSManagedObject that was created from the dataStore, and from each class i have a Class method to create the mapping of that RKEntityMapping.

My question is, how do i add data to an already existing object in the store.
For example when the app starts i download all the existing data form the server, but only after a couple of viewControllers i get userPermission or Facebook Data, so how do i add this data to the same object in the store? (do i need to create another entityMapping?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't use restkit, just use Core Data and NSJSONSerialization to construct your own bridge between networking and persistence.

Comment: I didn't fully understand your answer, how will i get the data from the my server/ FB server...?

Comment: Use NSURLConnetion / NSURLSession. Restkit is a very poorly implemented framework and will cause you more headaches then just using the system frameworks.

Comment: Hey Joride, can you please elaborate more about why RestKit is poorly implemented? I haven't had any chance writing a big application with it, so I'm not very familiar with it and it's down-sids, only familiar with it's pro's. Thanks

Comment: The model mapping is a very fragile thing. It uses SBJSON instead of the much faster NSJONSerialization and it makes no use of NSURLSession, the next gen of NSURLConnection. In short: the framework is unning behind in its usage of system technologies and uses dated third party libraries. Also, the mapping model to core data is an extra lauer of maintenance for you that is really unneccessary. Less headaches when you make your own A) data layer B) networking layer and C) parsing/retrieval layer. Plus, most likely you can parse your own data mich faster.

Comment: @Joride, it doesn't use `SBJSON` by default (depending on which version of RestKit you're using), and `SBJSON` is generally faster than `NSJONSerialization`. `NSURLSession` is new and a large change, it takes time to update (and that is work-in-progress). Of course you can write code which works faster than RestKit, but the point is you're then writing your own code instead of just specifying some mappings and getting on with real work...

Comment: Well, who am I to tell people what to do. Just use whatever you think is best actually. If you can justify using one thing or another, than go for it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need an extra entity mapping. Once RestKit has downloaded and processed all of your data into your local data store you can use Core Data as you usually would (with fetch requests) to interrogate and update that local data.